# Is it safe to delete .qgd files in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis-3

I am managing some of my QGIS 3 map files in a git repository. With QGIS 2, the map files (`.qgs`) are text files, which can be easily handled by git; QGIS3 introduces an additional binary file (`.qgd`) which presumably stores some auxiliary information. A compressed binary format `.qgz` is also provided with QGIS 3. These binary formats are not text line based, and difficult to manage using text oriented tools such as `diff` and `git`. Therefore, I do not want to track them in a repository unless I have to.

*How critical is the `.qgd` file?*

*Can I delete them or omit them when I use `git` to commit a map without seriously messing up the map?*

(I'm OK with loss of auxiliary information. Just need basic layer information and basic symbology to be committed, i.e. the choices of symbology and logical expressions I entered when defining a layer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> QGIS3 introduces an additional binary file (.qgd) which presumably stores some auxiliary information

It stores the *Project > Properties > Auxiliary Storage* information.

> A compressed binary format .qgz is also provided with QGIS 3

*.qgs* and *.qgd* files are comppressed into the *.qgz* file.
You can save the project as *.qgs* in QGIS 3, and will save the *.qgd* file.
But if you use the *.qgz* format you don't have a *.qgd* file.
Or you can unzip it and obtain both *.qgs* and *.qgd*.

> How critical is the .qgd file?

If you don't use [Auxiliary Storage](https://oslandia.com/en/2017/10/17/auxiliary-storage-support-in-qgis-3/) in your project, the *.qgd* file is empty and you can omit it.