# Difference between .qgs and .qgz

Tags: qgis, qgs, qgz

What is the difference between the .qgz and .qgs project file formats in QGIS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other answer correctly explains that a .qgz file is primarily a zipped container containing the .qgs XML file describing the project. This is described in https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/appendices/qgis_file_formats.html

However, the .qgz zipped container may also contain sidecar files. At the present time, these are:

1. Since 2017/2018, a .qgd file containing auxiliary storage such as custom labeling for layers in the project. See [Is it safe to delete .qgd files in QGIS 3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311317/is-it-safe-to-delete-qgd-files-in-qgis-3) for more information.
2. Since 2023, a project style database with extension .db (see https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/c6beb62216fcfbfe3ca64283c09117da53800a98) covering styles unique to the project.

Answer (score 7):

When I searched Google for 'qgz qgs difference' I found [“QGZ” – A new default project file format for QGIS](https://oslandia.com/en/2018/06/01/qgz-a-new-default-project-file-format-for-qgis/):

> Last year we had the opportunity to implement ‘.QGZ’ as  anew variant
>   of  the QGIS 3 project file format.
>
> This is simply a zipped container for the QGS xml file.