# Is it safe to omit the xyz_styles.db in .qgz?

Tags: qgis, file-formats

I like the .qgs format (which is basically a XML file), since I can quickly edit-replace it as a text document to bulk-update file paths/layer names. Also it is nicely usable with version control (github). Therefore whenever I can, I work only with the .qgs (vs. the compressed .qgz Container). So far I understood that I only need additional files in the .qgz if I'm making use of the [auxiliary storage](https://oslandia.com/en/2017/10/17/auxiliary-storage-support-in-qgis-3/), which I learned [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311317/is-it-safe-to-delete-qgd-files-in-qgis-3).

**QGIS 3.28 apparently introduced a .db file in the .qgz container** - called *uOdkeP_styles.db* in my case (where the first part is probably randomly generated).

**The name suggests that this contains styles**. [This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/455715/34517) suggests the same. The [current doc](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/appendices/qgis_file_formats.html) ([also on github](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/blob/master/docs/user_manual/appendices/qgis_file_formats.rst)) isn't mentioning the .db. I also experience an (unusual) backwards incompatibility: QGIS projects saved with 3.28 won't be properly displayed in 3.16.11 (which I'm still using for some old plugins) - vector layers are all blue there. This speaks for styles being stored there and older QGIS versions not knowing about it being unable to read them.

**BUT apparently the .db isn't needed for styles/symbology**: To verify I deleted the ..._styles.db, leaving only the .qgs file. But all my layers still appear fully styled. Unlike the name/backward incompatibility suggest, the .qgs without .db is sufficient to correctly store (my) symbology.

However QGIS 3.28+ likes to have those .db files around: Exporting to QField (which creates a .qgs) or saving a .qgs creates instead an additonal [QGS-project-name]_attachments.zip that then contains one or more (for me probably "empty" 1KB) ...styles.db.

**What do I need the ..._styles.db for?**
Is it "safe" to delete them, i.e. do I loose anything if I do?

[image: Unlike the name/backward incompatibility suggest, the .qgs without .db is sufficient to correctly store (my) symbology.]